# why does my console show nothing in pyhon?

Tags: python

This is my coding

[image]

below one is the screenshot of the lecture

[image]

I would like to know why my console does not show anything, unlike the lecture.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture but it looks like you are not executing any of those functions that are defined

Comment: Please post code directly as text in case we need to copy/paste and run it ourselves.

Comment: hello @swellz, I added the whole coding..

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the photos but it looks like you're not calling the function? and if you are, maybe with the wrong parameters, can you upload all of your code?